# How to convert multiple bit fields (8 per set) from database to byte in model

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, mapping

I keep bit fields as separate fields in database because of possible bit-related queries (those are digital inputs / outputs) with 8 bits per input/output with 2 to 4 inputs/outputs per table. I didn't normalize those fields into another table with inputs/outputs, because of poor ratio of storage to data (like 2x 4B keys and 2-3B of data in one of the nicer ways to store them).

I am using db-first approach and EF generated me bool properties for all of those bit columns. Currently I am reading those fields with bit shifts and bool logic. I am reading properties into an array and doing bit-logic with them to get the byte, array looks like this:

`bit[] bits = new bit[8] { DO_0, DO_1, ... , DO_7 };`

I am setting properties using array of setters, like this:

`Action<bool>[] bitSetters = new Action<bool>[8] { (x) => DO_0 = x, (x) => D0_1 = x, ...};`

The problem is I have to create array of values from properties and array of setters for every bit column I got in model. Is there another way? Especially using some features of EF.

Comment: So you want to convert bits to `byte`? `00001111` to `15` ?

Comment: Yes, but this is not the problem. The problem is a sane way to connect multiple bool properties without creating too much copies of the same code to connect multiple sets of bools. Or using EF to show bytes instead of bools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out how to make it in sane manner: complex type. I've created new complex type with 8 boolean properties and additional byte property that does conversion on the fly.